# Flutter app crashing when using social_share and social_share_plugin together

Tags: java, android, facebook, flutter, android-manifest

I am facing this issue when trying to share to Facebook Feed using social_share_plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/social_share_plugin).

The app is crashing after showing these errors:

```
Content provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider already published as com.game.brainybugs.com.shekarmudaliyar.social_share
```

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, The authority of the uri content://com.game.brainybugs.social.share.fileprovider/files/share_icon.png does not match the one of the contentProvider: com.game.brainybugs.com.shekarmudaliyar.social_share, null)
```

My AndroidManifest.xml looks like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.game.brainybugs">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.persmission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Play and Learn English"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon">
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
            android:value="@string/app_name"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.com.shekarmudaliyar.social_share"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths"
                tools:replace="android:resource"/>
        </provider>
        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider0000000000000000"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true"/>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.social.share.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"
                tools:replace="android:resource"/>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

where 0000000000000000 is my Facebook App ID obtained from developer.facebook.com

**Things I have tried:**

1. Using social_share only - **Works**
2. Using social_share_plugin only - **Works**

I need the ability to share to both Facebook Feed and Whatsapp which has compelled me to use both **social_share_plugin and social_share together**.

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I am facing same problem.

Comment: final file = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
                      source: ImageSource.gallery,
                    );
                    SocialShare.shareOptions(
                      file!.path,
                    ).then((file) {
                      print(file);
                    });  || how to share attach image and pdf to gdrive ?